# Discrete analogy of partial integral formula.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Show that discrete analogy of partial integral formula as below.
$$
 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} y(k)\Delta x(k)=x(n)y(n)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x(k+1) \Delta y(k) + c 
$$

I have tried as below and I stuck.

\begin{align*}
  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} y(k)\Delta x(k)&=
  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} y(k)\left(x(k+1)-x(k)\right)\\
  &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(x(k+1)y(k)-x(k)y(k)\right)\\
  &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x(k+1)y(k)- \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x(k)y(k)\\
 \end{align*}

Now I can't expand it in form

$$=x(n)y(n)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x(k+1) \Delta y(k) + c.$$

Anyone can give me hint?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} y(k)\Delta x(k)&=
  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} y(k)\left(x(k+1)-x(k)\right)\\
  &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(x(k+1)y(k)-x(k)y(k)\right)\\
  &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(x(k+1)y(k)-x(k+1)y(k+1)+x(k+1)y(k+1)-x(k)y(k)\right)\\
  &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(-x(k+1)(y(k+1)-y(k))+x(k+1)y(k+1)-x(k)y(k)\right)\\
  &=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x(k+1)\Delta y(k)+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(x(k+1)y(k+1)-x(k)y(k)\right) \\
  &=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x(k+1)\Delta y(k)+  \left(x(n)y(n)-x(0)y(0)\right).
 \end{align*}
Let $c=-x(0)y(0)$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} y(k)\Delta x(k)&=x(n)y(n)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x(k+1)\Delta y(k) +c.
\end{align*}